# Why is cURL running in a subshell?

Tags: curl

On my CentOS 7 box, I run something like:

```
$curl boxname:5000/page
```

And the output is:

```
$curl boxname:5000/page
[1] 55068

$ curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'boxname'

[1]+ Exit 6          curl boxname:5000/page
```

I'm not bothered about it not resolving the hostname, that's expected here. The question is - why is curl running in a subshell?  I need it to not spawn a new job so that I can check the exit code.

Comment: Add the _actual_ URL that you are trying to access. It most likely contains a `&` character.

Answer (score 2):

If the actual URL contains an unquoted `&` character, the command up until that point will be interpreted by the shell as a command to run in the background. The rest of the URL would then be taken as a new command.

Always quote URLs when specifying them on the command line. This also prevents other characters in the URL from being interpreted as special by the shell (e.g. `;` and `?` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The URL I was using had an ampersand in it!

Comment: And this is why it's important to give us real values and not make it up.